# sqlite incremental data backup every 5 minute

Tags: c#, sqlite, mariadb, wal

I'm using `sqlite` database for storing my data, a application which keep writing to the database non-stop. (example windows perf data every 5 minutes)

What I need,

1. get all the data incremental every 5 minutes and move to some log/text file
2. delete that piece of data which successfully move to log/text file from the `sqlite` db.

I have all below 3 files generated while I'm writing data to db.

1. MyData.db
2. MyData.db-shm
3. MyData.db-wal

I know may be based of last event insert time, query the data, process and delete, store last time in some place and next time read from that point onward.

I there a way that I can copy the `Wal` file in a incremental way every 5 minute to skip read/delete operation through C#?

I'm also open to change the database like Maria, etc, if other database provide this kind of solution, etc. Please suggest.

Comment: How to back up a sqlite database that is currently in use: https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html (just blindly copying files is a bad idea)

Comment: You'd need the [session extension](https://www.sqlite.org/sessionintro.html). This is probably not available with your C# driver.

Answer (score 1):

Why have a database involved at all?  Especially if you remove the data from it minutes after inserting it?

Plan A:  Append to a file.  Have some daily task to 'cycle' the file.

Plan B:  Store all the data 'forever' in MariaDB.  Suggest using `PARTITIONs` to facilitate purging "old" data.  For example, with ~32 partitions, you could have daily partitions.  Each night `DROP` the oldest partition and `REORGANIZE` to get a new partition.